# Is $8x^2-8y^2$ factorable or prime?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Edit: From Blitzer Intermediate Algebra 6th edition, page 371

> In exercises 23 - 48, factor completely, or state that the polynomial is prime

Edit 2: These set of problems focus on factoring using sum and difference of cubes, although that's not explicitly stated in the instructions. Perhaps within that context $8x^2-8y^2$ is considered prime?

My textbook says $8x^2-8y^2$ is prime, but couldn't $8$ be factored out and then factor using the difference of squares?

$8x^2-8y^2$

$8(x^2-y^2)$

$8(x+y)(x-y)$

Since the textbook claims $8x^2-8y^2$ is prime, why couldn't the polynomial be factored using the above method?

Comment: You may have to go deeper into the context for this question to make any sense, since you have already shown that $8x^2-8y^2$ is not prime.  Are there conditions on $x,y,$?

Comment: Just the fact that we can factor an 8 out of the difference means that it's not prime.

Comment: @BigBear If the problem is asking if this is prime in $\mathbb R[x,y]$, which judging by "factorable or prime" is exactly what it asks, then factoring out the 8 is not enough.

Comment: $8$ would be considered a unit in that context

Comment: You should state the entire question: where exactly should this be factorable? If the question is asking if this is factorable in $\mathbb R[x,y]$ then you are right. On another hand, if the question is in $\mathbb R[x^2,y]$ or $\mathbb R[x,y^2]$ or $\mathbb R[x^2,y^2]$, then the answer is "prime"...

Comment: @AndrewChin I have added the exact instructions provided by the textbook. It does not state any other conditions. My guess is  $8x^2 -8y^2$ is prime because those set of problems focus on factoring by sum and difference of cubes, although that's not explicitly stated.

Comment: @N.S. I have added the exact instructions. Unfortunately, the textbook does not give very detailed instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the level of math that the book is about, the answer should just be $8x^2-8y^2$ is factorable.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought but wasn't sure. I suspect the author wanted that set of problems factored using difference or sum of cubes, so within that context $8x^2 -8y^2$ would be "prime." Thank you.